# Form object's event can't see inherited method

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-7

**Problem summary:** The `OnClick` event of a `TForm` object says that it can't find the method I specify; this method is defined in the Form's superclass, which I expected it to be inherited.

Here I define the base type (i.e. superclass) for the "RAM Editor" window, including a button and what its `OnClick` event should do.

```
// File: RAM_Editor_Common.pas
type
  TfrmBaseRamEditor = class(TForm)
    btnMapfileLaden: TToolButton;
    procedure MapfileLaden1Click(Sender: TObject);
    // ....

procedure TfrmBaseRamEditor.Mapfileladen1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not OpenDialog2.Execute then Exit;
  StatusBar1.Panels[2].Text := OpenDialog2.FileName;
end;
```

Here I define the sub-class:

```
// File: RAM_Editor_SXcp.pas
TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp = class(RAM_Editor_Common.TfrmBaseRamEditor)
```

Here the sub-class's Form makes use of the button and sets the `OnClick` event to the method that was defined in the super-class:

```
// File: RAM_Editor_SXcp.dfm
object frmRAM_Editor_SXcp: TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp
// ....
// ....
    object btnMapfileLaden: TToolButton
      Left = 75
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Mapfile laden'
      Caption = 'btnMapfileLaden'
      OnClick = MapfileLaden1Click
      ImageIndex = 5
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = False
    end
```

But when I attempt to compile I get the error:

"The `MapfileLaden1Click` method referenced by `btnMapfileLaden.OnClick` does not exist. Remove this reference?"

Why can it not see the inherited method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your .dfm file is incorrect instead of:

```
object frmRAM_Editor_SXcp: TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp
```

you need

```
inherited frmRAM_Editor_SXcp: TfrmRAM_Editor_SXcp
```

Similarly instead of:

```
object btnMapfileLaden: TToolButton
```

you need

```
inherited btnMapfileLaden: TToolButton
```

I guess you are trying to inject a common base class into an existing hierarchy. You've made the changes needed in the .pas file, but failed to make the corresponding changes needed in the .dfm file. The `inherited` keyword in the .dfm file is required by visual form inheritance.

Comment: Use the IDE to do that. File -> New -> Other -> Inheritable Items

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Based on another recent question, I think that the classes here already existed.

Comment: It maybe. What I meant is you don't have to manually edit the dfm.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Not if you are creating a new form. But if you want to take a form that derives from `TForm` and change its heritage, I've never found any other way.

Comment: Ok, then I deleted it. :) What I meant was I used the IDE for testing what I commented, and the new form's dfm did not include the sub objects.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It doesn't mention them unless you modify any properties. But when you do then you need to use the `inherited` keyword again.

Comment: Bravo! Thank you very much, again :) But I should let you know that it works if I only change the `object frmRAM_Editor_SXcp...` part to `inherited`. If I change the button to `inherited`, when I run the program, I get an exception "class EReadError with message 'Ancestor for `btnMapfileLaden` not found". Is it relevant that the base-class unit (`RAM_Editor_Common.pas`) doesn't have an associated `.dfm` file?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. You really should add a .dfm file for the common base class. My answer assumes that. You will confuse the heck out of the IDE otherwise. You can work out what it ought to look like by building something from scratch in the IDE and inspecting what the IDE produces. The fact that you put the button in the base class but only instantiate it in the derived class tells me that something is wrong. I am still reasonably convinced that you are selecting the wrong solution to your problem. The interface is the way to go.

Comment: Hmm I'll read into visual inheritance but I'm hesitant to add a base `.dfm` for fear that it could stop me from making the derived `.dfm` forms look/behave differently to the base class `.dfm`. The reason I'm not doing the interfaces is because it's a big unit that would require a lot of refactoring on top of writing all the intefrace code, and I'm under time-constraint.

Comment: Interfaces is a trivial solution that you could implement from beginning to end in 10 minutes. It is non-invasive and requires no refactoring. Quite the opposite of injecting common base class. If you simply must inject common base class, why are you putting published GUI members in the base class but not giving them .dfm mentions? That feels badly wrong and all my experience and intuition says that decision will return to bite you down the line.

Comment: Hmm I'll take a look at interfaces then. I spent the last 16 work hours with a broken build trying to create this base class so it will be a bit annoying throwing all that away just as I finally made it work hehe. I put the GUI members into the base-class because it doesn't follow the DRY principle if I copy-paste the same exact declarations in 2 places (in the derived classes).

Comment: @NewWorld Well, that's where you were before you started this change. You had two forms with some commonality, duplicated rather than inherited. I'm reluctant to cast judgement from this far away though. Beyond my strong feeling that the decoupling that interfaces allows feels right.